# jqGrid edit inline and modal popup

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm using jqGrid 4.6.0 in a project and have enabled both inline editing and editing in a modal popup. 
I have the following problem: if the user activates inline editing for more than one row then clicks the edit selected row button, the modal poup will open correctly and the row is no longer in inline editing mode, but when I navigate between the records of the grids the ones that are in inline edit mode will display the html code of the input element, not only the value.
Does this mean that I can't use both type of editing at the same time? Is there a event that I can trigger to cancel the inline edit of the row the same way it is canceled when clicking the "Edit selected row" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using both types of editing is not recommended
  (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)
- To cancel an inline edit use the restoreRow method (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)